# CakePHP Missing out AND statement on Query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a problem where I have a Find in Cakephp that is designed to look for users that are busy in a calendar app. However when I look at the MYSQL query it doesn't look right.

Find Statement:

```
$result = $this->EventsUser->find('all',array('conditions'=>array(
                    'OR' =>array( 
                            'AND' => array(
                                    'Event.start >=' => $search_from,
                                    'Event.end <=' => $search_to),
                            'AND' =>array(
                                    'Event.end >' => $search_from,
                                    'Event.end <=' => $search_to),
                            'AND' =>array(
                                    'Event.start >=' => $search_from,
                                    'Event.start <' => $search_to)

                    ),
                    'User.is_resource'=>1

            ),
                    'group'=>array('EventsUser.user_id')
            ));
```

Produces the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT `EventsUser`.`id`, 
   `EventsUser`.`event_id`, 
   `EventsUser`.`user_id`, 
   `EventsUser`.`status_id`, 
   `User`.`id`, 
   `User`.`role_id`, 
   `User`.`username`, 
   `User`.`password`, 
   `User`.`first_name`, 
   `User`.`last_name`, 
   `User`.`photo`, 
   `User`.`photo_dir`, 
   `User`.`email`, 
   `User`.`phone`, 
   `User`.`location`, 
   `User`.`cost_ctr`, 
   `User`.`color`, 
   `User`.`text_color`, 
   `User`.`token`, 
   `User`.`active`, 
   `User`.`is_resource`, 
   `User`.`category_id`, 
   `User`.`description`, 
   `User`.`created`, 
   `User`.`modified`, 
   `User`.`location_id`, 
   `User`.`mobile_number`, 
   `User`.`resource_fuel_card_pin`, 
   `User`.`resource_email_contact`, 
   `User`.`resource_office_hours`, 
   `User`.`resource_post_code`, 
   `User`.`resource_payroll_number`, 
   `User`.`line_manager_email`, 
   ( Concat(`User`.`first_name`, ' ', `User`.`last_name`) ) AS `User__name`, 
   `Event`.`id`, 
   `Event`.`user_id`, 
   `Event`.`name`, 
   `Event`.`description`, 
   `Event`.`start`, 
   `Event`.`end`, 
   `Event`.`all_day`, 
   `Event`.`is_recurring`, 
   `Event`.`recurring_id`, 
   `Event`.`active`, 
   `Event`.`created`, 
   `Event`.`modified`, 
   `Event`.`owner`, 
   `Event`.`cost_cntr_id`, 
   `Event`.`txt_message`, 
   `Event`.`status_id`, 
   `Event`.`reason_for_hire_id`, 
   `Event`.`othersite_postcode`, 
   `Event`.`other_description`, 
   `Event`.`checksheet_id`, 
   `Event`.`declined_notes`, 
   `Event`.`hash` 
FROM   `car_pool`.`events_users` AS `EventsUser` 
   LEFT JOIN `car_pool`.`users` AS `User` 
          ON ( `EventsUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` ) 
   LEFT JOIN `car_pool`.`events` AS `Event` 
          ON ( `EventsUser`.`event_id` = `Event`.`id` ) 
WHERE  ( ( `Event`.`end` > '2015-06-07 13:01' ) 
     AND ( `Event`.`end` <= '2015-06-12 13:01' ) ) 
   AND `User`.`is_resource` = '1' 
GROUP  BY `EventsUser`.`user_id`
```

It seems to be missing off AND statements. When I remove AND statements from the find it always just does the last one on the Find

Does anybody have any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OR array is not correctly defined. You have created an array with 3 identical keys (i.e., the 'AND')

Instead of this:

```
'OR' =>array( 
            'AND' => array(
                          'Event.start >=' => $search_from,
                          'Event.end <=' => $search_to),
            'AND' =>array(
                          'Event.end >' => $search_from,
                          'Event.end <=' => $search_to),
            'AND' =>array(
                          'Event.start >=' => $search_from,
                          'Event.start <' => $search_to)
                )
```

It should be this:

```
'OR' =>array( 
            array('AND' => array(
                          'Event.start >=' => $search_from,
                          'Event.end <=' => $search_to)),
            array('AND' =>array(
                          'Event.end >' => $search_from,
                          'Event.end <=' => $search_to)),
            array('AND' =>array(
                          'Event.start >=' => $search_from,
                          'Event.start <' => $search_to))
                )
```

Comment: Thanks, the query now works as I expected, however my logic is out. I'll get there!!

Answer (score 1):

PHP 101, using same key multiple times in an associative array will overwrite the previous values. You are using `'AND'` multiple times. Just remove the `'AND'` keys as ANDing is default behavior.